# Vue-router cannot binding data in a new tab

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Everything work fine inner tab, but when I open the link in the new tab. I getting this error.

[image: index]

1. This is my router link(tab index):

> ```
>  <router-link tag="a" class="cursor-pointer text-primary" :to="{path: 'articles/edit/'+props.row._id}">{{ props.row.title }}
> </router-link>
> ```

2. This is the target page:

**mounted:**

```
mounted () {
        const articleId = this.$route.params.id

        this.loadArticle(articleId)
    },
```

**Vuex**

```
export async function loadArticles ({ commit }, { currentPage, perPage, status, subscriptions, validFrom, validThrough, approved, active, category, search  }) {
    commit('setArticlesBegin')
    try {
        const query = {
            skip: (currentPage - 1) * perPage,
            limit: perPage,
            search : search || '',
            category: category || '',
            validFrom: validFrom || '',
            validThrough: validThrough || '',
            approved: approved || null,
            active: active || null,
        }
        if (status) {
            query.status = status
        }

        const  {total, articles} = await api.getAll(query, 'admin')
        commit('setArticles', {
            articles,
            total,
            currentPage
        })
    } catch (error) {
        commit('setError', error)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using spread operator ("...") in ArticleEdit.vue ?

I need to view more code to understand.